# Getting only value of custom fields in Google Suite User list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I have made Custom Fields in my Users in Google Suite. 
Category: Foresatt
Among them: 
Name: 'foresatt epost', type:email, number: multiple values

I would like to list these values using Google Script. I used this:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/apps-script

To write this code:

```
function listUsers() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    customer: 'my_customer',
    maxResults: 10,
    orderBy: 'email',
    projection: 'custom',
    customFieldMask:'Foresatt' 
  };
  var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs);
  var users = response.users;
  if (users && users.length > 0) {
    Logger.log('Users:');
    for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      var user = users[i];
      var foresatt = user.customSchemas;
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.primaryEmail, user.name.fullName, foresatt);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No users found.');
  }
}
```

That works, but I would like to get only the values. What I get now:

```
{Foresatt={
  foresatt_mob=[{value=X#X#X#X#, type=work}, {type=work, value=X#X#X#X#}, {type=work, value=X#X#X#X#}], 
  foresatt_epost=[{value=xx@xx.no, type=work}, {type=work, value=xy@xx.no}, {value=yy@xx.no, type=work}], 
  foresatt_navn=[{type=work, value=Xx}, {value=Xy, type=work}, {type=work, value=Yy}]
  }
}
```

What I would like to get: xx@xx.no, xy@xx.no, yy@xx.no

I have tried several things, but I'm afraid I'm not experienced enough.

```
var epost = foresatt.foresatt_epost;
```

Results in: TypeError: Cannot read property 'foresatt_epost'

```
var epost = foresatt('foresatt_epost');
```

Results in: TypeError: foresatt is not a function

Please advise me, how do I get only the values fram the field 'foresatt epost'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of `xx@xx.no, xy@xx.no, yy@xx.no` from the following object:

```
const object = {
  Foresatt: {
    foresatt_mob: [
      { value: "X#X#X#X#",type: "work"}, 
      { value: "X#X#X#X#",type: "work"},
      { value: "X#X#X#X#",type: "work"},
    ],
    foresatt_epost: [
      { value: "xx@xx.no", type: "work"},
      { value: "xy@xx.no", type: "work"},
      { value: "yy@xx.no", type: "work"},
    ],
    foresatt_navn: [
      { type: "work", value: "Xx"},
      { type: "work", value: "Xy"},
      { type: "work", value: "Yy"},
    ]
  }
}
```

In this case, the values can be retrieved from the  `object.Foresatt.foresatt_epost` array.

#### Sample script:

```
const object = {}; //Your object

const res = object.Foresatt.foresatt_epost.map(e => e.value);
console.log(res)  // Outputs: [ 'xx@xx.no', 'xy@xx.no', 'yy@xx.no' ]
```

- If `user.customSchemas` is the above object, the script is as follows.

```
var foresatt = user.customSchemas;
const res = foresatt.Foresatt.foresatt_epost.map(e => e.value);
console.log(res)
```

- If you want to retrieve the value as a comma separated string, you can use `res.join(",")`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

**Note**:
If there is no guarantee your property will exist in your `object`, you can do `(object.property||[]).map(...)` instead of `object.property.map(...)` to avoid the error *`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`*.

Comment: Thank you so much! You got me reading up on arrays (also nested arrays), objects etc. So  I included a check to see what type 'foresatt' is. I tried your code, but got an error, and then I realized – I needed an if-statement for cases where the custom fields are empty. And because of the if I think, I had to change the const to var.

Comment: My code now, after the if users and for i:

      var user = users[i];
      var foresatt = user.customSchemas;
      //var type = typeof(foresatt);
      if(foresatt == null) {
        var lengde = 0; 
        var epost = "";
      } else {
        var lengde = Object.keys(foresatt).length;
        var epost = foresatt.Foresatt.foresatt_epost.map(e => e.value);      
      }
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.primaryEmail, user.name.fullName, epost); //foresatt, object, matrise[0]

Comment: @Ingeborg I added a modification to the answer to address times when the property might not exist. Take a look at the **Note** at the end and see if its useful to you. Cheers!

Comment: @ZektorH Thank you for your support. I couldn't notice about the replying. I apologize for this. I think that it will be useful for OP.